# How Could I Create This Type of Machine?

Tags: basic

So I have a computer. It has programs on it already. If I delete those programs, I would be left with an operating system that is able to run commands. I could create my own programs from that point, but I would be limited to the constraints of the operating system already loaded onto the machine. What I would like to do is remove the operating system from the computer entirely and be left only with a blank screen and a cursor where I could type whatever I want. I want to be able to create my own program without having to run an operating system program behind it. I do not understand how the physical machine would be able to process the strings of characters that I type into it and produce its own response, which would then be displayed on the screen, but obviously someone has done it before, otherwise I would not have the machine that I am typing on right now.

(I apologize for the run on sentences but I do not know how to say what I want to say right now.)

My goal here is to have a computer, kind of like the Apple 2, where the only thing that I could do with it is type into a text line and see characters pop up on the screen. My goal on top of that goal is to develop a program that would hide in the background of the machine, so that there would still only be a cursor on screen, but the program would make it so that when I type any simple question into the screen, such as, "How are you feeling today?", I would receive a response like, "I am doing quite well, thank you. How are you?".

Does anybody have any idea how I would be able to start this project properly?

Comment: You're misunderstanding what an operating system does.

Comment: @SLaks Then is there an operating system out there that is no more complex than what I desribed? I do not want search bars or icons or anything at all. I want a screen that I can type into that will understand the keys that I type.

Comment: @SLaks are you at least able to explain how the Apple 2 was able to do what I am describing?

Comment: @AngusCaceres It has an operating system.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you need to ask this question, you need to learn more than one answer on SO can provide.
2. Operating system is needed even to get the cursor thingy on screen.
3. If you are serious about the idea - you might want to start with a microcontroller, such as Arduino. They are more powerful than Apple 2 and they will allow you to write programs and boot straight into them. Adding some kind of terminal IO will not be hard - at least comparing to bootstrapping a program on an actual PC.

Comment: Thank you for the honest response, It will truly be a help. Is there a language that you would recommend I learn first? I just read that Arduino is written in Java, but would it make sense to learn C or C++ before that?

Comment: C, definitely - if you want to run on bare metal. Arduino is not "written" in anything, since it's a piece of hardware. But its "official" language is a superset of C as well. Beware, this is a rather long journey, so learn to enjoy the views along the way and don't focus so much on arriving. So to speak.

Comment: If actual PC means x86 with a BIOS and all you want is a text prompt it isn't that hard to start with the boot sector of a floppy disk or USB thumb drive.

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point for a project like this is to learn about operating systems in general. It is a vast topic but you don't have to know everything.

When we speak of an operating system we have in mind a large system that provides capabilities like managing memory, reading and writing files to permanent storage and interacting with input and output such as keyboards and displays. We are also usually thinking of a large number of higher level software applications. Think about commands like dir or ls as programs that come along with the operating system. Of course with a GUI based OS we also have windows and buttons and a wide variety of controls to consider.

The good news is that in order to get started you don't need to be an expert on everything and you certainly don't have to start with a full-blown OS.

The other good news is that the topic can be broken down into byte-sized pieces. A great introduction to the fundamentals you will need is Charles Petzold's [Code The Hidden Language of Hardware and Software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code:_The_Hidden_Language_of_Computer_Hardware_and_Software)

> Petzold begins with discussions of the inventions of Morse code and Braille, adds electricity, number systems, Boolean logic, and the resulting epiphanies required to put them all together economically. With these building blocks he builds circuits, relays, gates, switches, discusses the inventions of the vacuum tube, transistors, and finally the integrated circuit.
>
> The last portion of the book contains a grab bag of subjects such as implementation of floating point math, operating systems, and the various refinements that have occurred in the latter half of the twentieth century.

Once you have a feel for the fundamentals a good next step in learning about operating systems is to study one that provides as few capabilities as possible. Take a look at [MINIX](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/10754)

> MINIX originally was developed in 1987 by Andrew S. Tanenbaum as a teaching tool for his textbook Operating Systems Design and Implementation. Today, it is a text-oriented operating system with a kernel of less than 6,000 lines of code. MINIX's largest claim to fame is as an example of a microkernel, in which each device driver runs as an isolated user-mode process—a structure that not only increases security but also reliability, because it means a bug in a driver cannot bring down the entire system.

Have fun.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think this will the most helpful answer to any question I've had in a long time.

Comment: @angusCaceres you can mark this answer as accepted if it answers your question. By marking accepted it will help others find it.